# Not able to parse JSON data from text file using python script

Tags: python, json, jsondecoder

I have a '.txt' file that contains JSON data like below.

```json
[{'tradable': True, 'mode': 'full', 'instrument_token': 4708097, 'last_price': 178.65, 'last_traded_quantity': 5, 'average_traded_price': 180.1, 'volume_traded': 4581928, 'total_buy_quantity': 1282853, 'total_sell_quantity': 1673842, 'ohlc': {'open': 181.95, 'high': 181.95, 'low': 177.8, 'close': 181.0}, 'change': -1.2983425414364609, 'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 4, 58), 'oi': 0, 'oi_day_high': 0, 'oi_day_low': 0, 'exchange_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 5, 1), 'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 653, 'price': 178.6, 'orders': 8}, {'quantity': 2408, 'price': 178.55, 'orders': 15}, {'quantity': 6329, 'price': 178.5, 'orders': 22}, {'quantity': 9161, 'price': 178.45, 'orders': 24}, {'quantity': 7775, 'price': 178.4, 'orders': 17}], 'sell': [{'quantity': 5726, 'price': 178.7, 'orders': 8}, {'quantity': 4099, 'price': 178.75, 'orders': 11}, {'quantity': 23951, 'price': 178.8, 'orders': 25}, {'quantity': 7446, 'price': 178.85, 'orders': 21}, {'quantity': 11379, 'price': 178.9, 'orders': 21}]}}, {'tradable': True, 'mode': 'full', 'instrument_token': 871681, 'last_price': 972.55, 'last_traded_quantity': 1, 'average_traded_price': 973.85, 'volume_traded': 411290, 'total_buy_quantity': 152925, 'total_sell_quantity': 214765, 'ohlc': {'open': 971.75, 'high': 978.6, 'low': 969.0, 'close': 967.75}, 'change': 0.4959958667011061, 'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 4, 53), 'oi': 0, 'oi_day_high': 0, 'oi_day_low': 0, 'exchange_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 5, 4), 'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 6, 'price': 972.15, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 3, 'price': 972.1, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 15, 'price': 972.05, 'orders': 3}, {'quantity': 455, 'price': 972.0, 'orders': 16}, {'quantity': 14, 'price': 971.95, 'orders': 2}], 'sell': [{'quantity': 6, 'price': 972.5, 'orders': 3}, {'quantity': 49, 'price': 972.55, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 10, 'price': 972.6, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 27, 'price': 972.65, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 10, 'price': 972.7, 'orders': 1}]}}]
```

This data was written to a .txt file after it was recieved from zerodha websocket. Now, I want to read the data from the .txt file using my python script and want to load it as a json. But the `json.loads()` method in python throws the below error.
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

I have tried `eval` and `ast.literal_eval` methods in python as well but it didn't solve my problem. All I want is to be able to read the above data as a JSON to my python script. Any leads would be of great help.

Comment: Unfortunately the text file does not contain `json` format data. It looks like it was just printed. So `ast.literal_eval` should work.

Comment: Better is to create the file contents from `json.dump()`.

Comment: @quamrana `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't work: `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Call object at 0x7f567f957850>`

Comment: Did you create this text file, or were you given it? If you created it, then you should change the method of creating it to use `json.dump` as already suggested.

Comment: That data has four `datetime.datetime` objects. JSON does not have a datetime type.

Comment: What did you try with `eval()` exactly? If you got `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined`, you just need to `import datetime` first. (That said, `eval()` is a last resort, but I don't see another option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start off with **THIS IS A BAD IDEA**.

The comments on the question call out that this is not a JSON object in a file, rather the result of some other Python process printing the result and putting that in a file. The correct solution would be to modify the producer to use `json.dumps()` instead.

That aside, here's a **DANGEROUS** way to read that source file into a Python object.

```py
import datetime  # needed for `eval()`

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = eval(f.read())

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

This will produce the following output from that input:

```
[{'average_traded_price': 180.1,
  'change': -1.2983425414364609,
  'depth': {'buy': [{'orders': 8, 'price': 178.6, 'quantity': 653},
                    {'orders': 15, 'price': 178.55, 'quantity': 2408},
                    {'orders': 22, 'price': 178.5, 'quantity': 6329},
                    {'orders': 24, 'price': 178.45, 'quantity': 9161},
                    {'orders': 17, 'price': 178.4, 'quantity': 7775}],
            'sell': [{'orders': 8, 'price': 178.7, 'quantity': 5726},
                     {'orders': 11, 'price': 178.75, 'quantity': 4099},
                     {'orders': 25, 'price': 178.8, 'quantity': 23951},
                     {'orders': 21, 'price': 178.85, 'quantity': 7446},
                     {'orders': 21, 'price': 178.9, 'quantity': 11379}]},
  'exchange_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 5, 1),
  'instrument_token': 4708097,
  'last_price': 178.65,
  'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 4, 58),
  'last_traded_quantity': 5,
  'mode': 'full',
  'ohlc': {'close': 181.0, 'high': 181.95, 'low': 177.8, 'open': 181.95},
  'oi': 0,
  'oi_day_high': 0,
  'oi_day_low': 0,
  'total_buy_quantity': 1282853,
  'total_sell_quantity': 1673842,
  'tradable': True,
  'volume_traded': 4581928},
 {'average_traded_price': 973.85,
  'change': 0.4959958667011061,
  'depth': {'buy': [{'orders': 2, 'price': 972.15, 'quantity': 6},
                    {'orders': 2, 'price': 972.1, 'quantity': 3},
                    {'orders': 3, 'price': 972.05, 'quantity': 15},
                    {'orders': 16, 'price': 972.0, 'quantity': 455},
                    {'orders': 2, 'price': 971.95, 'quantity': 14}],
            'sell': [{'orders': 3, 'price': 972.5, 'quantity': 6},
                     {'orders': 2, 'price': 972.55, 'quantity': 49},
                     {'orders': 1, 'price': 972.6, 'quantity': 10},
                     {'orders': 2, 'price': 972.65, 'quantity': 27},
                     {'orders': 1, 'price': 972.7, 'quantity': 10}]},
  'exchange_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 5, 4),
  'instrument_token': 871681,
  'last_price': 972.55,
  'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 4, 53),
  'last_traded_quantity': 1,
  'mode': 'full',
  'ohlc': {'close': 967.75, 'high': 978.6, 'low': 969.0, 'open': 971.75},
  'oi': 0,
  'oi_day_high': 0,
  'oi_day_low': 0,
  'total_buy_quantity': 152925,
  'total_sell_quantity': 214765,
  'tradable': True,
  'volume_traded': 411290}]
```

Again, I will restate, **THIS IS A BAD IDEA**.

Read more on the specifics of `eval` here: https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/

Comment: To explain briefly why it's a bad idea: `eval()` allows for arbitrary code execution, so it should never be used on untrusted input. Personally, I would even be hesitant to use it on trusted input just in case the code ever ends up being run on untrusted input by accident.

Comment: The data is from a trusted source, and this solution works fine for me. I had tried the 'map' function but can't recollect what I did wrong. Either way, thank you @Mike Fiedler

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. You can check that by using an online JSON validator like this one: https://jsonformatter.org/

After entering the “JSON”, you can see it is not in a valid format.
You could either export it right, which I would highly recommend, or you could replace the wrong chars.

Currently, you have three issues:

1. You are using single quotes instead of double quotes
2. You are not parsing your datetime object, it looks like you just insert the object, you have to serialize it
3. You are writing **true** values as **True**, but that is the python way and not the JSON way. You either have to write it as **true**, or you have to pass it as a string. I would recommend the first one.

It could look like this (but I didnt parse datetime right, I just stringified it):

```
[{"tradable": true, "mode": "full", "instrument_token": 4708097, "last_price": 178.65, "last_traded_quantity": 5, "average_traded_price": 180.1, "volume_traded": 4581928, "total_buy_quantity": 1282853, "total_sell_quantity": 1673842, "ohlc": {"open": 181.95, "high": 181.95, "low": 177.8, "close": 181.0}, "change": -1.2983425414364609, "last_trade_time": "datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 4, 58)", "oi": 0, "oi_day_high": 0, "oi_day_low": 0, "exchange_timestamp": "datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 5, 1)", "depth": {"buy": [{"quantity": 653, "price": 178.6, "orders": 8}, {"quantity": 2408, "price": 178.55, "orders": 15}, {"quantity": 6329, "price": 178.5, "orders": 22}, {"quantity": 9161, "price": 178.45, "orders": 24}, {"quantity": 7775, "price": 178.4, "orders": 17}], "sell": [{"quantity": 5726, "price": 178.7, "orders": 8}, {"quantity": 4099, "price": 178.75, "orders": 11}, {"quantity": 23951, "price": 178.8, "orders": 25}, {"quantity": 7446, "price": 178.85, "orders": 21}, {"quantity": 11379, "price": 178.9, "orders": 21}]}}, {"tradable": true, "mode": "full", "instrument_token": 871681, "last_price": 972.55, "last_traded_quantity": 1, "average_traded_price": 973.85, "volume_traded": 411290, "total_buy_quantity": 152925, "total_sell_quantity": 214765, "ohlc": {"open": 971.75, "high": 978.6, "low": 969.0, "close": 967.75}, "change": 0.4959958667011061, "last_trade_time": "datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 4, 53)", "oi": 0, "oi_day_high": 0, "oi_day_low": 0, "exchange_timestamp": "datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 13, 5, 4)", "depth": {"buy": [{"quantity": 6, "price": 972.15, "orders": 2}, {"quantity": 3, "price": 972.1, "orders": 2}, {"quantity": 15, "price": 972.05, "orders": 3}, {"quantity": 455, "price": 972.0, "orders": 16}, {"quantity": 14, "price": 971.95, "orders": 2}], "sell": [{"quantity": 6, "price": 972.5, "orders": 3}, {"quantity": 49, "price": 972.55, "orders": 2}, {"quantity": 10, "price": 972.6, "orders": 1}, {"quantity": 27, "price": 972.65, "orders": 2}, {"quantity": 10, "price": 972.7, "orders": 1}]}}]
```